# How to read image using OpenCV got from S3 using Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, opencv, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a bunch of images in my S3 bucket folder.

I have a list of keys from S3 (`img_list`) and I can read and display the images:

```
key = img_list[0]
bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(bucket_name)
img = bucket.Object(key).get().get('Body').read()
```

I have a function for that:

```
def image_from_s3(bucket, key):

    bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(bucket)
    image = bucket.Object(key)
    img_data = image.get().get('Body').read()

    return Image.open(io.BytesIO(img_data))
```

Now what I want is to read the image using OpenCV but I am getting an error:

```
key = img_list[0]
bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(bucket_name)
img = bucket.Object(key).get().get('Body').read()
cv2.imread(img)


SystemError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-9561b5237a85> in <module>
      2 bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(bucket_name)
      3 img = bucket.Object(key).get().get('Body').read()
----> 4 cv2.imread(img)

SystemError: <built-in function imread> returned NULL without setting an error
```

Please advise how to read it in the right way?

Comment: You need `img = cv2.imdecode(buffer)` when you aren't reading from disk.

Comment: @MarkSetchell buffer in this case will be ```bucket.Object(key).get().get('Body').read()```?

Comment: Probably, I don't know what's in your buckets.. it should begin with `0xff0xd8` in hex if JPEG.

Comment: @MarkSetchell my bucket consists of folders one of them contain all the PNG images.
I have PDF there too but this is another issue.
I would like to connect to S3 (which I have done), take the key and pass it to cv2.
Here is the error I am getting:
TypeError: imdecode() missing required argument 'flags' (pos 2)

Comment: The flags are just the same as `cv2.imread()`.

Comment: Doesn't work - it shout on buffer...
How would you get an image from S3 directly to cv2? Is there any working example @MarkSetchell?

Comment: Please show the first few (20-30) bytes of the variable `img` in hex or whatever. Please also get the length of the buffer, i.e. `len(msg)` and the dimensions of the image in there in pixels, e.g. `640x480 pixels of RGB` or `1920x1080 pixel of greyscale`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell here is the img first bytes:
b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x04\xb8\x00\x00\x04\r\x08\x06\x00\x00\x00^\xa2\xf3\x90\x00\x00\x01DiCCPICC Profile\x00\x00(\x91c``\x12I,(\xc8aa``\xc8\xcd+)\nrwR\x88\x88\x8cR`\x7f\xc2\xc0\xc2 \xc2\xc0\xcd\xc0\xc9\xa0\x9f\x98\\\\\xe0\x18\x10\xe0\x03T\xc2\x00\xa3Q\xc1\xb7k\x0c\x8c \xfa\xb2.\xc8\xac\x0b~\xc7O\xa6

Comment: ```len(img)``` is 498033 @MarkSetchell

Comment: image size : (1208, 1037) @MarkSetchell

Comment: Ok, that looks like a perfectly legitimate PNG image, so you should be able to read it with `array = cv2.imdecode(img, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)`

Comment: Nope @MarkSetchell Here is the error I am getting: TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'buf'
when I run:
```array = cv2.imdecode(img, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)```

Comment: @MarkSetchell please explain this part of your answer:
np.asarray(bytearray(img))

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sorry, I got it wrong in the comments. This code sets up a PNG file in a memory buffer to simulate what you get from S3:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import cv2

# Create new solid red image and save to disk as PNG
im = Image.new('RGB', (640, 480), (255, 0, 0))
im.save('image.png')

# Slurp entire contents, raw and uninterpreted, from disk to memory
with open('image.png', 'rb') as f:
   raw = f.read()

# "raw" should now be very similar to what you get from your S3 bucket
```

Now, all I need is this:

```
nparray = cv2.imdecode(np.asarray(bytearray(raw)), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

So, you should need:

```
bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(bucket_name)
img = bucket.Object(key).get().get('Body').read()
nparray = cv2.imdecode(np.asarray(bytearray(img)), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

Comment: Worked!!!
Can you please correct me if I am wrong: you are reading it with bytearray because it's given as bytes and then transfer to a matrix?

Comment: `imdecode()` seems to want a Numpy array and AFAIK, `np.asarray()` creates exactly that from a `bytearray` without copying so it should be fairly fast. There may be other ways of doing it (I'm no expert) so if anyone does know, please ping me. Btw, I think you may not be able to change the Numpy image you get unless you make a copy with `myCopy = nparray.copy()` or you change the original `np.asarray(...)` to `np.array(...)`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have sent you an email (on your site). My pleasure!
@mark-setchell

Answer (score 3):

Hope This will be Best Solution For Mentioned Requirement, To read The Images from s3 bucket using URLs..!

```
import os
import logging
import boto3
from botocore.client import Config
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
import numpy as np
import urllib
import cv2

s3_signature ={
'v4':'s3v4',
'v2':'s3'
}



def create_presigned_url(bucket_name, bucket_key, expiration=3600, signature_version=s3_signature['v4']):

    s3_client = boto3.client('s3',
                         aws_access_key_id="AWS_ACCESS_KEY",
                         aws_secret_access_key="AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY",
                         config=Config(signature_version=signature_version),
                         region_name='ap-south-1'
                         )
    try:
        response = s3_client.generate_presigned_url('get_object',
                                                Params={'Bucket': bucket_name,
                                                        'Key': bucket_key},
                                                ExpiresIn=expiration)
        print(s3_client.list_buckets()['Owner'])
        for key in s3_client.list_objects(Bucket=bucket_name,Prefix=bucket_key)['Contents']:
            print(key['Key'])
    except ClientError as e:
        logging.error(e)
        return None
        # The response contains the presigned URL
    return response

def url_to_image(URL):
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    image = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()), dtype="uint8")
    image = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

    return image


seven_days_as_seconds = 604800

generated_signed_url = create_presigned_url(you_bucket_name, bucket_key, 
seven_days_as_seconds, s3_signature['v4'])
print(generated_signed_url)
image_complete = url_to_image(generated_signed_url)

#just debugging Purpose to show the read Image
cv2.imshow('Final_Image',image_complete)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Use For Loop to iterate to all Keys In The KeyList. Just Before calling the Function create_presigned_url.

Comment: Note : please change url to URL in the resp

Comment: Very nice code for processing image from s3. but can you please help me how to read multiple images from s3 to cv2.

Comment: you can do this in one line url=s3.generate_presigned_url('get_object', Params={'Bucket': s3BucketName, 'Key': documentName}) no need to loop through and list objects

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative using `download_fileobj` and `BytesIO`:

```py
from io import BytesIO

import cv2
import numpy as np

bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(bucket_name)
file_stream = BytesIO()
bucket.Object(key).download_fileobj(file_stream)
np_1d_array = np.frombuffer(file_stream.getbuffer(), dtype="uint8")
img = cv2.imdecode(np_1d_array, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```