# How to read multiple images from aws s3 bucket to cv2.imread in python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I have tried this link [How to read image using OpenCV got from S3 using Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61461753/how-to-read-image-using-opencv-got-from-s3-using-python-3/63380403#63380403) but how to get multiple images from s3 bucket to process through cv2.imread ?

any related response is much appreciated, Thank you in advance.

Comment: What problem are you facing with the code that you linked to? The `create_presigned_url()` function in the code seems to be creating a URL that can be used to access an object. It would just be a matter of calling it once for each image you want to reference. Please edit your question to include details of what you have tried so far.

Comment: Thank you for response, my question is how to iterate with for loop in key to read all images ? i only get single image url !! but i need multiple images with url_to_image() but i only get single image url :(

Comment: Just call it multiple times, once for each image.

Comment: Thats not practical, if i have 100 images then i cant access that way but only by autmatically accessing and preocessing with for loop i += 1

Comment: If you do not wish to use pre-signed URLs, another option is to download the files to the local disk, then refer to those files directly.