# How to read image from S3 using OpenCV (cv2.imread)?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, opencv, amazon-s3, image-processing

I am having trouble reading images from the S3 bucket. I can read images locally like that.

```
def load_image(path):
    image = cv2.imread(path)
    image = cv2.resize(image, (224, 224))
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    return image

for image_path in os.listdir(path):
    image = load_image(path + "/" + image_path)
    X.append(image)
```

But I have no idea why S3 said error

```
TypeError: Can't convert object of type 'list' to 'str' for 'filename'
```

Comment: Which line is giving the error? Where is the part that is using S3? Where is the reference to `filename`? I don't think you're showing us everything relevant.

Comment: That's expected, `opencv` does not support reading from S3, you have to code yourself reading of the data from S3. It's not difficult, just a few extra lines.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63380403/14286182

Comment: why does `path + "/" + image_path` result in a *list*? it's either that or you're hiding code. and where's the **complete traceback**? please review [mre]

Comment: Hi Chris, nope, that is how I code it up since my logic here is every image has its own path, so I just read all the images as a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first establish a connection to S3, then download the image data, and finally decode the data with OpenCV.

For the first bit (connecting to S3), Boto3 is a good alternative (it's the Python SDK for AWS).

Full sample code:

```py
from io import BytesIO

import boto3
import cv2
import numpy as np

endpoint_url = {your_s3_endpoint_url}
bucket_name = {your_s3_bucket_name}
key = {your_image_key_within_the_bucket}
aws_access_key_id = {your_aws_access_key_id}  # Better not to directly expose in source code
aws_secret_access_key = {your_aws_secret_access_key}  # Better not to directly expose in source code

bucket = boto3.resource(
                "s3",
                endpoint_url=endpoint_url,
                aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,
                aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key,
            ).Bucket(bucket_name)
file_stream = BytesIO()
bucket.Object(key).download_fileobj(file_stream)
np_1d_array = np.frombuffer(file_stream.getbuffer(), dtype="uint8")
img = cv2.imdecode(np_1d_array, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

Comment: Yah, it was a year ago, but I think that is the correct solution, which is how I approached it.